# MS Access linked workbook won't refresh after database split

Tags: excel, ms-access, frontend

I have a number of workbooks that link to an Access database and draw data via queries. I recently split the database to fe/be and distributed the front end to various users.

Some users, **but not all of them** cannot refresh the data in some of the workbooks. They receive the error message: "The query did not run or the table could not be opened. Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available and hasn't been moved or reorganized, then try the operation again".

I've tried changing the connection file in Excel's connection properties on their local machines to their personal front end, and also to my copy but got the same error message.

Here's the sql from one of the offending queries in case that helps identify the problem:

```
SELECT tblFitExtractMain.[Issue ID], tblFitExtractMain.[Date Entered], IIf([DateClosed] Is Not Null,Year([DateClosed]),IIf([DateMovedOutofShip] Is Not Null,Year([DateMovedOutofShip]),IIf([DateMovedIntoQualClosure] Is Not Null,Year([DateMovedIntoQualClosure]),Year([Date Entered])))) AS [Year], IIf([DateClosed] Is Not Null,Month([DateClosed]),IIf([DateMovedOutofShip] Is Not Null,Month([DateMovedOutofShip]),IIf([DateMovedIntoQualClosure] Is Not Null,Month([DateMovedIntoQualClosure]),Month([Date Entered])))) AS [Month], tblFitExtractMain.Status, tblProductMatrix.product_variant, IIf([product_variant]="G4" Or [product_variant]="G3" Or [product_variant]="CLM","Pulsed","Systems") AS [Product line], IIf([DateArrivedatSPIUK] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutof4SPIIncoming] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateArrivedatSPIUK],[DateMovedOutof4SPIIncoming]),IIf([DateArrivedAtSPI] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutof4SPIIncoming] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateArrivedatSPIUK],[DateMovedOutof4SPIIncoming]),IIf([DateMovedOutofTransit] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutof4SPIIncoming] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedOutofTransit],[DateMovedOutof4SPIIncoming]),Null))) AS [Section 4 pre], IIf([Section 4 pre]=0,1,Abs([Section 4 pre])) AS [Section 4 calc], IIf([DateMovedIntoPreliminary] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutOfPreliminary] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedIntoPreliminary],[DateMovedOutOfPreliminary]),IIf([DateMovedOutof4SPIIncoming] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutOfPreliminary] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedOutof4SPIIncoming],[DateMovedOutOfPreliminary]),Null)) AS [Section 5 pre], IIf([Section 5 pre]=0,1,Abs([Section 5 pre])) AS [Section 5 calc], IIf([DateMovedIntoEngInv] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutOfEngInv] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedIntoEngInv],[DateMovedOutOfEngInv]),IIf([DateMovedOutOfPreliminary] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutOfEngInv] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedOutOfPreliminary],[DateMovedOutOfEngInv]),Null)) AS [Section 6a pre], IIf([Section 6a pre]=0,1,Abs([Section 6a pre])) AS [Section 6a calc], IIf([DateMovedInto6bCommRevReplace] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutof6bCommRev] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedInto6bCommRevReplace],[DateMovedOutof6bCommRev]),IIf([DateMovedOutOfEngInv] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutof6bCommRev] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedOutOfEngInv],[DateMovedOutof6bCommRev]),Null)) AS [Section 6b pre], IIf([Section 6b pre]=0,1,Abs([Section 6b pre])) AS [Section 6b calc], IIf([DateMovedOutof6bCommRev] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutof7Rep] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedOutof6bCommRev],[DateMovedOutof7Rep]),IIf([DateMovedOutOfEngInv] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutof7Rep] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedOutOfEngInv],[DateMovedOutof7Rep]),Null)) AS [Section 7 pre], IIf([Section 7 pre]=0,1,IIf([Section 7 pre]<0,Null,[Section 7 pre])) AS [Section 7 calc], IIf([DateMovedIntoShip] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutofShip] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedIntoShip],[DateMovedOutofShip]),IIf([DateMovedOutof7Rep] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutofShip] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedOutof7Rep],[DateMovedOutofShip]),IIf([DateMovedOutof6bCommRev] Is Not Null And [DateMovedOutofShip] Is Not Null,DateDiff("d",[DateMovedOutof6bCommRev],[DateMovedOutofShip]),Null))) AS [Section 8 pre], IIf([Section 8 pre]=0,1,[Section 8 pre]) AS [Section 8 calc], IIf([DateClosed] Is Not Null,[DateClosed],IIf([DateMovedOutofShip] Is Not Null,[DateMovedOutofShip],IIf([DateMovedIntoQualClosure] Is Not Null,[DateMovedIntoQualClosure],[Date Entered]))) AS [Date closed], tblProductMatrix.power, tblFitExtractMain.[Warranty Status]
FROM tblFitExtractMain INNER JOIN tblProductMatrix ON tblFitExtractMain.[Serial Number(1)] = tblProductMatrix.serial_number
WHERE (((Left([Status],1))>="9"));
```

Many thanks

Comment: I'd try linking the sheets to the back end instead of the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue, but using a MS SQL back end with Excel.  Add a temporary new sheet to their workbook and create some quick query that pulls data from the updated connection into the temporary sheet.  If data does not come through this method, try adding a new connection with the same properties/string and see if the data pulls through to the temporary sheet.  This will at least isolate the problem, hopefully you don't have to manually update each affected users to a new connection object.

If you have many users, this could be cumbersome.  My situation, users did not have personalized workbooks so I was able to have employees simply start using the new XLS file.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this & got the puzzling message "The database contains no tables" when selecting the front end as the data source & could not proceed any further. Of course it contains no tables, it's a front end!

Comment: Why are you pointing a workbook at an Access front end with no tables? I am confused. Why point at it at all after splitting the tables into a separate file, is it because of legacy you can't clean up?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. I'm using the front end as I'm drawing data via queries, not direct from the tables. For ease of maintenance I'd much rather use queries in Access than specify the SQL at connection level in the users workbooks. I don't think this is unusual.

Comment: This makes sense. I agree, that is much easier for maintenance if queries / tables might change.  Have you tried copying the exact workbook file from a user that has success, and try opening it in the profile of a user who gets the error?  This could rule out if it is specific to the users Windows profile / Office profile or to their copy of the file. To clarify, workbook -> front end Access DB -> BE Access DB. Front end and workbook copies reside with user, BE resides on server?